# Setting up ufw without locking yourself out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, ufw

Basically I want to protect a Ubuntu server with a firewall and sided for ufw.
The big problem is that I don't have physical access to the server, neither is it possible to force a reboot or revert to a snapshot. So locking myself out is not an option.

I'm using ssh with public key authentication on the alternative port 567(for example) for remote administration.

Which rules and configurations are required to keep the ssh access open?
Are there any ways to automatically reset the firewall if anything fails?

Comment: Use [firehol](http://firehol.org/) instead of ufw.  Then when starting a new ruleset use `firehol try`.  Which will start the new rules, and then wait for ~30 seconds for you to confirm that you still have access.  If you don't confirm your rules are reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cron to do this. Have it reset to a known good default set of rules every 30 minutes (or whatever) or so.

Comment: Could you get more specific on how to do this with ufw?